# How to apply template to the scrollbar of a listbox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollbar

I have a very simple question. I know this is possible but since I am new to XAML so may be I cant express it properly and thus google doesnt help me.

In simple words:

I want to apply a template to the Scrollbar in the ListBox ?

How ? any example would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dig in a bit into the template, what you need to change is the ScrollBar inside the ScrollViewer template.

It's a bit complex, but there are good tutorials walking through each bit, like this: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/04/styling-listbox-in-silverlight-part-2.html

Comment: That is just tooo much code. Too much. Yuck.

But thanks a lot for this example. Helps a lot.

Comment: Most of it is just default templates, if you have Expression Blend you can get it to generate it for you and only change what you need. If it helped, please marked the answer as accepted ;)